# Fixed checkbox column in EXTJS panel

Tags: extjs, checkbox, extjs4

Team,

Is Anyone aware of disabling horizontal scroll on checkbox column
 remain fixed and other column's scroll properly working.

I tried

```
     bodyStyle:'overflowY: auto',

     autoScroll:false,

     setAutoScroll:false,
```

on particular checkboxSelectionModel and try to override property but it's not working.

i'm using ExtJs 4.0

Example: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-a7A-q_ni5v0/UrLau_s2bWI/AAAAAAAAAC8/GLKj4FJVZ5E/s1600/chkbox_grid1.PNG

see this image i'm talking about checkbox column, and on that note i remove that scroll property on that particular column.

Comment: Do you mean pinning the first column in a grid?

Comment: i mean not a 1st column , a checkbox model column.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for

> **lockable**: If the grid is configured with enableLocking, or has columns which are configured with a locked value, this option may be
> used to disable user-driven locking or unlocking of this column. This
> column will remain in the side into which its own locked configuration
> placed it.
>
> **locked**: True to lock this column in place. Implicitly enables locking on the grid. See also Ext.grid.Panel.enableLocking.

Link to Documentation: [Ext 5.0](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-locked)

And here is a sample: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/grid/locking-grid.html

Comment: Thanx for answered But, i'm talking about a particular checkbox column which is bydefault generated by ExtJs . so, in that selection model this property is not working.

Comment: @KunjanShah - please update question with that detail. Question doesn't mention that.

Comment: BTW, checkcolumn also has the above two config properties

Comment: yes, you are right but that properties are not working on ExtJs 4.1.0

Comment: locking is also available in 4.1.0 - http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel

Comment: but its working on grid and i'm searching for this property on selectioncombo box model. BTW i'm trying that and its not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76538/discussion-between-kunjan-shah-and-seram).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
Ext.define("My.extension.LockedCheckBoxSelModel", {
extend: "Ext.selection.CheckboxModel",

getHeaderConfig: function () {
    return {
        isCheckerHd: true,
        text: '&#160;',
        width: 24,
        sortable: false,
        fixed: true,
        hideable: false,
        menuDisabled: true,
        dataIndex: '',
        locked: true,//here's the difference
        cls: Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'column-header-checkbox ',
        renderer: Ext.Function.bind(this.renderer, this)
    };
}});
```

And if you will use this extension instead of default CheckboxModel, like `selModel: Ext.create('My.extension.LockedCheckBoxSelModel')`, first column with checkbox should be locked. But you might have to enable grid locking, so specify grid's **enableLocking: true** property, or set **locked: true** on some of grid's columns

Comment: After Searching on google i checked that  "locked : true" and  worked on ExtJs 4.1.1 or above version , but i'm using ExtJs 4.1.0 so, any other solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Add enableLocking: true in your grid's config. It will lock the selection model and enables the lock/unlock option for every column